# URL folder hierarchy changes using mod_rewrite in .htacess file

Tags: php, css, apache, .htaccess

I made an website with php and I wrote .htacess file in my htdocs folder:

> ```
> RewriteEngine on 
> RewriteBase /
>
> RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ ?mainquery=$1 [QSA]
>
> RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ ?mainquery=$1&subquery=$2 [QSA]
> ```

My Intention is to redirect the url:

> '/A/B' => '/?mainquery=A&subquery=B'.

If the main query is one, everything works fine.
but when the url has two queries, php works fine, but the folder hierarchy moves, so every images and css files with relative urls doesn't work.

It works fine that

> (I'm building my web on MAMP, so the domain is now localhost.)
>
> 'localhost/publications/articles' => 'localhost/?mainquery=publications&subquery=articles'

but the html thinks the main url is *'localhost/publications'*, not just *'localhost/'*.

so every img tag which has src attribute like

> img src='images/myImage.jpg'

doesn't work, because the html thinks the image is in *'localhost/publications/images/'*, not *'localhost/images/'*.

So does css file.

I'm pulling my hair for 3 days, but I can't solve it myself.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: To mark a question solved, click the checkmark to accept an answer below. Don't tag your question solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ ?mainquery=$1&subquery=$2 [QSA]
```

To this:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /?mainquery=$1&subquery=$2 [QSA]
```

The rewritten rule need to be root-relative, else it's going to be relative to the requested URL, which is in a sub-folder already.

I *think* that's what you're asking. If you're just asking how to point to images/css/js root-relative, change this:

```
<img src="images/myImage.jpg" />
```

To this:

```
<img src="/images/myImage.jpg" />
```

Comment: Oh god, I solved it simply adding '/'s in front of urls! Thanks very much!